# certbot works in command line but fails when running through django call to script

Tags: python, django, centos7

So I have been dealing with this problem for days now and have exhausted every possible thing I can think of.

For clarification purposes I am running

**Machine**: Centos 7

**WebServer**: Django

**Python Version**: 3.6

I have this shell script at /usr/local/bin/activate_https_hostedvoice

```shell
#!/bin/bash

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | sudo -S curl -i -XPOST "http://<REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY>/records/""$1""/""$2"""

sleep 10

NGINX_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/nginx/guiconf.d/guiserver.conf

sed -i "s/]/,'""$1""']/g" /var/lib/guiserver/astgui2/db_pass.py

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "/sbin/service guiserver reload" root

echo "" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}

echo "server{" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}

echo "server_name $1;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}

echo "client_max_body_size 4G;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}

echo "include guiconf.d/server_params;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}
echo "include guiconf.d/static_files;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}
echo "include guiconf.d/web_path;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}
echo "include guiconf.d/local_path;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}
echo "include guiconf.d/ws_path;" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}

echo "}" >> ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE}


echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "systemctl reload nginx" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "systemctl stop iptables" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "certbot --nginx -d ""$1"" --agree-tos --email <REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY> -n" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "systemctl reload nginx" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "systemctl start iptables" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "/sbin/service guiserver reload" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c 'echo "0 */12 * * * certbot --nginx renew -n" >> /var/spool/cron/root' root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "rm -f /var/lib/guiserver/bin/https_config" root

echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "echo ""$1"" >> /var/lib/guiserver/bin/https_config" root
```

Whats happening here is first I am sending a curl request to add the A record to the nameserver.
Then I am adding the appropriate configurations for nginx

I then reload nginx and stop iptables so that certbot can reach the server

When I run this script in the command line `bash /usr/local/bin/activate_https_hostedvoice <some_domain> <some_ip>`

The script runs flawlessly and the A record is instantly pingable.

However when I run the script through django like so

```python
os.system('echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | su -c "bash /usr/local/bin/activate_https_hostedvoice ' + domain + ' ' + points_to + ' > /tmp/http_activate_log " root');
```

I can see that the A record is added to the nameserver and the nginx configuration values get added but when it comes to certbot this is the output that I receive

```html
The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: <REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY>
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for <REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY>
   - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
```

Upon the script exiting I then try to ping the A record and it is unpingable for several minutes on the server but if I try on my local computer or another computer and ping the domain its pingable

From the command line I have run over 30 test back to back and they have all gone through successful this issue only occurs when I call the script from django and it makes no sense to me

**Update on the issue:**

After further testing if I run `curl -i -XPOST "http://<REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY>/records/<some_domain>/<some_ip>"`

straight on the command line then it is not pingable instantly so I put it in a script and ran `bash /tmp/test <some_domain> <some_ip>`

Then the domain was pingable instantly

So naturally I changed the original script to be
`bash /tmp/test ""$1"" ""$2""`

instead of
`echo "<REMOVE_FOR_SECURITY>" | sudo -S curl -i -XPOST "http://<REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY>/records/""$1""/""$2"""`

But I am still having an issue with it not being pingable instantly

Thanks Joseph

Comment: I would recommend using full path's for all commands. On my Mac, I get different values for `$PATH` when using `print(os.environ['PATH'])` vs. `os.system('/usr/bin/env > /tmp/env.txt')`. Possibly at least on command cannot be found in `$PATH` and you are not checking on errors. Using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) might be a better option ...

Answer (score 0):

i try this step and worked. just one line at a moment.

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
sudo yum remove python-urllib3 -y
sudo yum remove python-requests -y
sudo yum install python-urllib3 -y
sudo yum install python-requests -y
sudo yum install certbot python2-certbot-nginx
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```